# How to name Groovy Traits?

Tags: naming

Classes should be nouns and methods should be verbs. What about [Groovy traits](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html)? Should they also be nouns? Or maybe should they be adjectives / ability words?

Answer (score 3):

Finding inspiration from other languages (C# in this case), **interfaces** are generally used as traits, i.e. particular behaviors. For example, consider `IDisposable` and `IEnumerable`.

You see the same thing happen on the page you linked:

```
class Person implements Greetable {                     
    String name() { 'Bob' }                             
}
```

However, keep in mind that interfaces can in some cases be a noun. For example, `IList`.

You can also see the same thing happen on the page you linked:

```
trait FlyingAbility {                           
    String fly() { "I'm flying!" }          
}
```

When you think about it, an adjective wouldn't have worked here. "Flyable" does not mean "able to fly" (e.g. a bird is able to fly), it means "able to *be flown*" (e.g. a plane can be flown by a pilot). In order to avoid confusion, the noun form was a better choice here.

Trying to distill a naming description for interfaces, the focus is not really on whether it's a noun or an adjective, but rather that **it describes an ability**. This can be done in noun form (`FooAbility`) or adjective form (`FooAble`), but the intention is the same: pointing out the ability to do/be something.

Whether you choose a noun or an adjective depends on the semantics surrounding the word (in the language that your code is written in, which is not always English).

> ***Sidenote***
>   *In codebases that use dependency injection, core classes (`Foo`) get a boilerplate interface (`IFoo`). This breaks the naming convention of pointing out an ability, unless you read it as meaning "able to behave as a `Foo`", which I don't quite agree with. In my opinion that inverts the logic. We should instead think of it as "`Foo` can behave as an `IFoo`" (because of `Foo : IFoo`).*
>
> *Regardless, DI interfaces have a slightly different naming convention, but they are not really used as "traits" anyway, so I'm choosing to ignore them for your specific question on traits.*

---

**Edit**

Come to think of it, the distinction between noun/adjective seems to be related to active/passive voice.

- (adjective) Flyable = able to be flown (passive)
- (adjective) Throwable = able to be thrown (passive)
- (adjective) Flammable = able to be set on fire (passive)
- (noun) FlyingAbility = able to fly (active)
- (noun) ThrowingAbility = able to throw something (active)
- (noun) FireAbility = able to set fire to things (active)

I'm not sure if this is universally applicable in English. I'm not sure if this applies to other languages.

Comment: Flyable = able to be flown.  "Flow" means something else entirely.  :)

Comment: @Neil: Edited the typo.

Comment: "volitational"?

Comment: @Ewan Volitational is defined as ["relating to flying"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/volitational). That's not the same as "able to fly". It doesn't describe an ability, it denotes a relation.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volitation

Comment: I think you are wrong. It means 'has the power of flight' in this context and would be clearly understood by any reader as it is a common English word and much more clearer than FlyingAbility.  Chinese restaurants serve Chinese food, It is the recipe which has the property

Comment: as with all questions about the english language there is a simple solution. What does the Queen think it means? we just need to ask her